# Button event not raised when controls added to panel on Page_Init on UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have code in Page_Init that adds code to Panel

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      PopulateQuotePanel();
}

private void PopulateQuotePanel(string searchText = "")
{
    pnlQuote.Controls.Add(GuiHelper.CreateGUITable(guitems))
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //does stuff
}
```

code snipped for simplicity.

ASP.NET

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateSearch" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Panel ID="pnlQuote" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
     <br />
     <asp:Button ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_Click" runat="server" Text="Save Quote" />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When the page loads and I click the button. The event btnSave_Click is never raised.

Comment: Where is the code for the btnSave_Click event?

Comment: the event is never raised, neither are other buttons on the page

Comment: without being able to see the outputted HTML, I would guess that somewhere in the PopulateQuotePanel, there is something that is messing with the DOM

Comment: I think your right the Page_Init function is being called on postback

Comment: Cool. If not, as a last-ditch solution, copy the code, delete the btn_click event code from the cs file, delete the button, save then recreate the button. I have seen times when writing the code manually confuses it

Comment: Its something to do with adding the items dynamically to the Panel, when I comment out the add line the events are fired. just looking into those functions in detail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143721/discussion-between-welsh-king-and-simon).

Comment: sorry. site is blocked at work

Comment: no worries, ive just done a test and it appears that adding the code in a table is causing the problem, im just debugging